# Unable to access chrome runtime using selenium and chrome headless mode

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, f#, google-chrome-headless

I have a simple F# project which use *Selenium* and *Chrome*. I noticed that when Chrome is launched in *headless* mode the chrome object is not defined.

On the other side, if I run it "normally" the chrome object is correctly referenced.

Sample code:

```
let chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions(BinaryLocation = _chrome)
chromeOptions.AddArguments
    (
        "--headless", 
        "--disable-gpu"                    
    )
let chrome = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions, Url = "http://www.example.com")

try                
    Console.WriteLine(chrome.Capabilities.Platform)
    Console.WriteLine(chrome.Capabilities.BrowserName)
    Console.WriteLine(chrome.Capabilities.Version)
    let res = chrome.ExecuteScript("return chrome;")
    Console.WriteLine(res)
with e -> 
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message)

chrome.Quit()
```

If I run the code above I got the following output:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8) on port 61158
Only local connections are allowed.
Any
chrome
62.0.3188.0
unknown error: chrome is not defined
  (Session info: headless chrome=62.0.3188.0)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)
```

If I omit the *headless* option I got the following output:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8) on port 60248
Only local connections are allowed.
Any
chrome
62.0.3188.0
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]
```

Is this a bug or I am missing something?

Comment: `headless` is a very recent feature of chrome and you will find differences from the normal browser which may not be documented yet. So it is very difficult to say if it is a bug or it a feature that will be missing

Comment: Are you using Chrome 62?,but chromedriver 2.31 will support till Chrome 60 as per their [release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.31/notes.txt)

Comment: Unfortunately also by using chrome _60.0.3112.101_ I get the same error :\

Comment: I think I didn't understand your question properly. Can you help me to understand the data type of `res`? What exactly are you trying to print through the console?

Comment: sure, the print was just to demonstrate my issue. My real goal is to execute a script which uses the chrome runtime in order to send a message (via _chrome.runtime.sendMessage_) to an extension that I previously loaded. 
This extension logs all the requests and responses exchanged with the server. 

Afaik this is the only method available to get such info with Selenium.